# How to write long exception statements avoiding rubocop line length error

Tags: ruby, coding-style

I'm using a `rescue` statement exceeding the length of 120, because of which `Rubocop` shows offences. What should be the best way to write it?

**Original statement:**

```
 rescue ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound, ActiveResource::BadRequest, ActiveResource::TimeoutError, ArgumentError => e
```

**Modified Statement:**

```
 rescue ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound, ActiveResource::BadRequest, ActiveResource::TimeoutError,
    ArgumentError => e
```

But it doesn't look right and also not readable. What is the best way to write it?

Comment: Why doesn't it look right?

Comment: In the sense it is not readable as such. Any other way around to write in a better way?

Comment: I don't understand why you feel it not readable.

Comment: You can disable rubocop checking by adding line # rubocop:disable Metrics/LineLength before your code and same line but with 'enable' after

Comment: @sawa: There are lots of line of code after this rescue command so this  `argument => e` gets a bit confusing is on the next line. Some one can misinterpret it as another line of code.

Answer (score 2):

When I have a long list of errors to rescue, I generally handle it like this:

```
class MyClass < Object
  HandleTheseErrors = [
    ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound,
    ActiveResource::BadRequest,
    ActiveResource::TimeoutError,
    ArgumentError
  ]

  def do_something
    begin
      # do something error prone
    rescue *HandleTheseErrors => e
      puts e
    end
  end
end
```

The `*HandleTheseErrors` says, pass each of the elements of the `HandleTheseErrors` array as arguments to the rescue method.

Comment: This is interesting! I don't know what to think about it yet, so I'm sticking with "interesting." :-)

Comment: That's a nice solution. But i can't add it to my code as there will lots of changes then. :'(